# how to understand the foreach function in scala in my case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In test.txt, data are like

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

my code:

```
   val reader = sparkSession.read.csv("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt")

    val sb = new StringBuffer()

    reader.foreach(row=>{
      val colname = row.get(0)
      val colval = row.get(1)
      val str = s"""$colname=$colval"""
      sb.append(str)
      println(sb) // get output
    })

    println(sb)  // get nothing
```

I don't know how to explain why the outside `println(sb)` get nothing to println in a professional perspective, please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code outside `foreach` runs on the master, but code inside `foreach` runs on an executor. `StringBuffer` inside `foreach` is a copy of the outside `StringBuffer`. Thow all appends to `StringBuffer` happen on an executor and the outer `println(sb)` gets unmodified `StringBuffer`.

Comment: how to get the modified stringbuffers which are on executosr to master?

Comment: You can't do this. But you can write something like reader.map(row => s"${row.get(0)}=$row.get(1)").collect and collect all rows strings into master.

Comment: Note that that would blow up the stack if the are many data. You may also try a reducer. But more importantly, you first have to understand that **Spark** is a distributed processing engine, you have to understand its execution model and what consequences does it has. This classical problem of the foreach not working _(this is asked at least once per weak)_ always means that person who is asking had not understood that all operations on **Spark** are executed in different jvms usually in different machines.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, I'm just a rookie and don't have a basic understanding on the running theory in spark. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @jayWong I understand and respect that, we all have been / are / will be new to something. And by comment was not really personal too you. It is just that I do not understand why it always happen, why all the people want to start a new technology just by writing code instead of understanding the concepts and basic theory of those technologies. Lately most questions on SO that I see, would not be done, if the poster would have read the basic documentation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think there are several reason for that. First, actually we may read the spark documentatition but not smart enough the apply these concepts well to the real case. Second, some guys are pushed to output before dealine with no time understanding the concepts. BTW, I'll appreciate that if you can recommend some books or websites or papers of spark concept and details? Thanks again.

Comment: @jayWong Yeah of course, checkout the [original spark paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi12/nsdi12-final138.pdf), this [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data),  this [blog post](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) about memory management was very helpful too me, I also watched this _looooong_ [video](https://youtu.be/7ooZ4S7Ay6Y) when I was starting, not sure if it is still updated for today, but I guess the main concepts still apply. Finally obviously the official documentation, and remember the scaladoc is your friend.